# Плагин для просмотра картинок

Tags: jquery, javascript

С помощью какого плагина JQuery можно сделать такой [просмотр](http://www.lamoda.ru/shoes/men/tommyhilfiger-klassicheskiebotinki-to263ambk985/) изображения:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плагин [jQuery - Cloud Zoom](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm)